# Plot Chart Using Flot library in MVC4.0

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, flot

I am trying to load a jquery chart (FLOT), but struggling a lot while assigning datasource(Json) to chart in MVC4.0

Below code I am using to plot chart. I have used temp.var d2,d3,d4 and it shows graph. But I want to use json data from database to chart.

Code snippet is given below. How can I use Json data to bind data to Flot chart. In my chart, I have to show Date on Y-Axis and F_Rate on X-Axis and trendlines also which will be static like Upper limit and lower limit. 
Graph attached for ref.

Please suggest.

```
$(function () {

    //var d1 = [];
    //for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
    //    d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    //}

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    //Trendlines
    var d3 = [[0, 15], [15, 15]];

    var d4 = [[0, 8], [8, 8]];
    //End trend lines


// Debug using Firebugg,Json have data in format [{"1/1/2013",1.0001},{..}]
        $.getJSON("/Home/JsonValues", function (data) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           // var jdata = JSON.stringify(data);
           // $.each(JSON.stringify(jdata), function (i, el) {
                //alert(el.Id + ' - ' + el.TagNo);
            //});
        });




    var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
    var plot = $.plot(placeholder, [d2, d3, d4],
        {
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            }

        }

        );

    $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
        position: "absolute",
        display: "none",
        border: "1px solid #fdd",
        padding: "2px",
        "background-color": "#fee",
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body");


    $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

        if ($("#enablePosition:checked").length > 0) {
            var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + "," + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";
            $("#hoverdata").text(str);
        }

        if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
            if (item) {
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                $("#tooltip").html("(" + x + "," + y + "")
                    .css({ top: item.pageY + 5, left: item.pageX + 5 })
                    .fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $("#tooltip").hide();
            }
        }
    });



    // Add the Flot version string to the footer

    // $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});
```

```
<div id="content">

<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>

<p class="message"></p>
<p>
    <label>
        <input id="enablePosition" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>Show mouse position</label>
    <span id="hoverdata"></span>
    <span id="clickdata"></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>
        <input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>Enable tooltip</label>
</p>
```

Earlier help would be really much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your data has to be in the correct format for flot, that means

1. Array of arrays (datasets) of arrays (points), no objects
2. The datetime values must be converted to timestamps (see [the documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data))

The data should look like this:

```
[[[1356998400 ,1.0001], [1356998460, 1.5001]]]
```